# How can I show that $f(x)=0.25x^4+x^2y+y^2$ has a minimum point?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$\ f(x,y)=0.25x^4+x^2y+y^2 $$

The question is to Find the minimum point of $$\ f(x,y) $$

I first took partial derivative of f with respect to x and y

Then, I got 
$$\frac{\partial f_{}}{\partial x} =x^3+2xy$$
$$\frac{\partial f_{}}{\partial y} =x^2+2y$$

Then points when they both become zero is $$ y=\frac{-x^2}{2}$$

Then, I look at the Hessian Matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}3x^2+2y & 2x\\2x & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then once I plug in $$ y=\frac{-x^2}{2}$$

The matrix becomes

$$\begin{bmatrix}2x^2 & 2x\\2x & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Surely, the determinant of this matrix becomes 0, which implies that this matrix is not positive definite and therefore no min points exsist

I am wondering if there is something wrong with my approach

Comment: It might be easier to note that $f(x,y) = ({1 \over 2} x^2 +y)^2$. Hence there is a curve of minimisers.

Comment: Yeah, that is true. The question says that the hessian matrix of that function is positive definite. So, I am wondering whether this is a typo or there is an way to form a positive definite matrix.

Comment: At a minimum all you can show is positive demi definiteness of the Hessian. Look at the one dimensional example $x \mapsto x^4$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Positive definiteness of the Hessian matrix is a *sufficient* condition for $f$ to attain a local minimum. It is not a necessary condition. In other words, if the Hessian is not positive definite, it does not follow that no minima exist.

For your problem, you should plug $y=-\frac12x^2$ into the original function $f(x,y)$ to find that $f(x,y)=0$ when $y=-\frac12x^2$. This is the smallest that $f$ can possibly be, since you can complete the square in $\frac14x^4+x^2y+y^2$ to obtain $(\frac12x^2+y)^2$, which is nonnegative. So $f$ achieves its minimum value (namely zero) at any point $(x,y)$ such that $y=-\frac12x^2$.